# ember addons test-support directory

Tags: ember.js, ember-addon

I've some test helpers in my addon. I want to:

1. use these helpers for my addon's own tests.
2. make these helpers available to my addon's users, **for testing their own codes**.

[In the documentation](https://ember-cli.com/extending/#addon-project-structure), it is said that `test-support` can be used to satisfy the second requirement mentioned above; but I couldn't find a way to make it work for both.

Comment: Note that the docs say "_merged with the application’s tests/_", So the helpers you would like to share should be going into `test-support/helpers/`. It is hard to imagine what could be wrong going solely by the information you've given. You could take a look at an open source addon which also shares a helper, (like [emberx-select](https://github.com/thefrontside/emberx-select) shares their `select` helper)

Comment: I'll verify it on monday, but I think you are correct. So can you copy your comment as answer? So I can accept the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [docs](https://ember-cli.com/extending/#addon-project-structure) say "***merged*** with the application’s tests/",

An applications test-helpers reside in `test/helpers/`, any helper specified here should be registered automatically.

**When sharing an addons test-helper, make sure it resides in** `test-support/helpers`,

Once  the directory get merged, the file should end up in the `tests/helpers` directory and be registered automatically.

As a reference one could take a look at the [emberx-select](https://github.com/thefrontside/emberx-select) addon,
A "select"-helper is shared using the same method specified in this answer.